# How to (temporarily) disable McAfee Endpoint Security on an enterprise workstation?

Tags: windows, penetration-test, antivirus

I need to temporarily disable McAfee Endpoint Security on an enterprise workstation after having obtained local administrative privileges. The McAfee Endpoint Security settings are protected by a password.

I've tried to stop the McAfee service and attaching a debugger to various McAfee components, but every attempt results in "Access Denied" (also for Local System). The reason is probably a low-level McAfee driver running on the system.

Also, I've searched the registry for a password hash, suggested by old articles, but I cannot find anything under HKLM\SOFTWARE\McAfee.

Finally, I tried to change several McAfee services from "auto" to "disabled", which resulted in Windows unable to boot (bluescreen) until repaired.

Anyone with suggestions or experience on the issue?

```
McAfee Agent 5.5.1.342
McAfee Endpoint Security 10.6
```

Comment: Okay, _why_ are you trying to do this?  What big-picture task are you trying to accomplish? 
 Note that, especially on Windows, there's admin, and then there's "admin".

Answer (score 1):

I will address the administrative, not technical aspect of this question, because you have specified an Enterprise setting, and you do not seem to be an Enterprise Admin.

You are obviously working in Windows, so I will assume an Active-Directory managed infrastructure, and I will suppose that your McAfee workstation clients are centrally managed.

You should talk to your security people and to your own supervisor.  If you are in security, this should be that much simpler.  You should either be working from a service request or similar, which if assigned to you should cover your butt.  If not, you should get *written* permission from your supervisor to go about disabling things, and your supervisor in turn should have *written* permission from security.

If these things cannot be had, then I respectfully submit that you are engaged in a certainly dangerous (to security and to your career) and potentially rogue activity.  None of this means malicious -- I also presume that you are acting in good faith.

Taking the most positive case, let us assume that you are working as directed, and are struggling to get something done which the company agrees needs to be done.  But the implications of cowboying around with security settings can still compromise your environment, and of course your own position.  You may appreciate a piece of advice which I came up with the hard way -- "it is fatal to care more than the company does."

If the company cannot or will not provide you with top-cover and approved tools to accomplish changes, your efforts will likely lead to worse results, not better.

Back to the technical merits of the question: how?  Ask your security people.  They will know whether the clients are centrally managed, and what it takes to disable the service on a particular client.

More likely than not (I boldly surmise), this will involve moving the machine to a different OU (or GPO group, or similar) in Active Directory, or a similar process in your central management tool specific to the endpoint client.

Finally, if I knew how to do this on a per-machine basis, I still wouldn't post it here.

Comment: Don't you mean "it is fatal to care *less* than the company does."? I'm doing a penetration test, and the company want to assess if their AV is robust.

Comment: No, I mean *more*.  Show me how to take this to chat, and I'll be happy to expand.

Comment: It escapes me what sort of well-managed pen test this could be.